# Accounting for NA using Pivot_longer in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to `pivot_longer` 34 columns of a data set with about 10,000 rows in R. The data was collected via survey, and each column represents a possible answer to a question. I want to `pivot_longer` one of the questions, which had 34 possible answers, and account for 34/107 columns. The columns have a value (1) if that answer was selected, and the other 33 rows have NA.

Example subset of data frame for a question with 5 possible answers (`df`):

```
ID  A   B   C   D   E
1   1   NA  NA  NA  NA 
2   NA  1   NA  NA  NA
3   NA  NA  NA  NA  1
4   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 
5   NA  1   NA  NA  NA
```

I need to get to:

```
ID Answer
1  A
2  B
3  E
4  NA
5  B
```

I want to `pivot_longer` the results to this question, while maintaining all the other columns. The issue occurs because some people didn't answer this question, resulting in all NA's (See row 4).

I'm using the code:

```
dfNew <- pivot_longer(df, c(A,B,C,D,E), names_to = "Answer", values_drop_na = TRUE)
dfNew

ID Answer
1  A
2  B
3  E
5  B
```

Which removes ID 4 from the data. Not using `values_drop_na` results in having a row for every NA value in `A:E`. How do I get it to maintain ID 4 as part of the data set, and make the value for Answer NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `complete` to fill the missing values :

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, A:E, names_to = "Answer", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  complete(ID = unique(df$ID)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-value)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
#     ID Answer
#  <int> <chr> 
#1     1 A     
#2     2 B     
#3     3 E     
#4     4 NA    
#5     5 B
```

---

You can also use `max.col` here :

```
cbind(df[1], answer = names(df)[-1][max.col(!is.na(df[-1])) * 
                                 NA^ !rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)])
```

This might be quite difficult to understand.

1. `max.col(!is.na(df[-1]))` returns the index of non-NA value in each row but in case the row has all `NA`'s it returns any index.
2. `NA^ !rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))` this part returns `NA` for rows where there are all `NA`'s and 1 for rows which has atleast 1 non-NA.
3. When we multiply `1 * 2` we get `NA`'s for all `NA`'s row and row-index where there is a value.

```
max.col(!is.na(df[-1])) * NA^ !rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  1  2  5 NA  2
```

4 . We use these (above) values to subset column names from `df` to get `answer`.

```
names(df[-1])[max.col(!is.na(df[-1]))*NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]), na.rm = TRUE)]
#[1] "A" "B" "E" NA  "B"
```